# Make X axis wider and Y axis narrower in plotly

Tags: python, r, plot, plotly, plotly.js

I am trying to make the x axis of a surface plot wider (more space between each points in x) and y axis narrower (less space between points in y). Here is an example data

```
kd <- with(MASS::geyser, MASS::kde2d(duration, waiting, n = 50))
p <- plot_ly(x = kd$x, y = kd$y, z = kd$z) %>% add_surface()
```

I couldn't find a param that does this. I came across width param and tried the following, but didn't help

```
plot_ly(x = kd$x, y = kd$y, z = kd$z) %>% add_surface() %>% layout(title="test data",width=1000)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by making the x/y axis wider/narrower. Do you want to change the aspect ratio of your plot?

Comment: @MauritsEvers Yes I meant is aspect ratio. So the plot look more rectangular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the x axis wider using aspectratio

```
plot_ly(x = kd$x, y = kd$y, z = kd$z) %>% add_surface() %>% layout(scene = list(aspectmode="manual",aspectratio = list( x = 2, y = .5, z = 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `yaxis` or `xaxis` more bigger or smaller using `domain` parameter.
Such [here](https://plot.ly/r/mixed-subplots/#mixed-subplot).